# Sending a persistent message in RabbitMQ via HTTP API

Tags: api, http, rabbitmq, persistent

I want to send a persistent mesaage via HTTP API. Im using this command:

```
curl -u UN:PWD -H "content-type:application/json" -X POST -d'{"properties":{},"routing_key":"QueueName","payload":"HI","payload_encoding":"string", "deliverymode": 2}' http://url:8080/api/exchanges/%2f/amq.default/publish
```

My queue is durable and deliverymode is also set to 2(Persistent), but the messages published are not durable. What change needs to be done?
When I send the same via Management Console, the message is persistent but not via HTTP API.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`delivery_mode` is a properties, so you have to put it inside the `"properties"` as:

```
curl -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -X POST -d'{"properties":{"delivery_mode":2},"routing_key":"QueueName","payload":"HI","payload_encoding":"string"}' http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/amq.default/publish
```